# Unexpected break while reading a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to program a hex-viewer for cmd in python 2.7
It works almost fine, but if I try to view a compiled file on windows, it shows only a little part of it. I already figured out, that `read()` breaks at the first occurrence of `0x1a` (in ASCII). Notepad++ shows this char as SUB. I don't know what this control-character does, why `read()` stops at this char and how to avoid this break. Can anyone help me?

Here's my whole code:

```
    def main():

        while True:
            print "Enter a file path:"
            path = raw_input()
            f = open(path, 'r')
            text = f.read() # seems to break at 0x1a/SUB
            f.close()
            for c in text:
                hex_c = hex(ord(c))[2:]
                if len(hex_c) % 2: # if the hex number consists of 1 digit
                    hex_c = '0' + hex_c # fill the string with a zero
                print hex_c,
            print # just as a line break in the console

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f = open(path, 'r')` opens the file in *text* mode.

While it has little importance on Linux, if you stil use Python 2.x, on Windows, text mode enables end of line conversion (CRLF become LF aka `\r\n` become `\n` aka `0x0D 0x0A` becomes `0x0A`)

I must admit I cannot explain why you have this behaviour, but for a hex editor, you *have* open the file as binary or you'll lose all `0x0d` bytes (and other surprises I'm apparently unaware of, I'll make some more research):

```
f = open(path, 'rb')
```

no conversion is performed, file is accessed in raw mode, I cannot see how it wouldn't fix your problem.

(also don't forget to `f.close()` your file, as it's currently not done, or use a `with open(path,"rb") as f:` statement.

BTW: direct 2-digit hex can be achieved by: `hex_c = "%02x" % ord(c)`

EDIT: I tried with python 3, and it won't even let me read a binary file as text. I got `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 46: character maps to <undefined>`. At least you can't do it from the start!

Comment: Thank you very much! I am actually closing the file directly after the `read`-call, I just forgot to type the code line here.